# result of function that returns innerHtml is undefined, why

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="GeoElem">
</p>
```

// when pressing this button I should be redirected to url with the value calculated in Func2

```
<button id="myButton2" onClick=myFunct3()> Click me </button> 
<script>
```

//function that builds my url; Func2 returns undefined

```
function myFunc3() { 
        window.location.href = window.location.href + "/search/" + Func2();
    }
```

//need Func2 to call Geo which calculates the position into the inner html of element

```
function Func2() { 
Geo(); 
var x = document.getElementById("GeoElem"); 
return strip(x.innerHTML); //return the innerHTML
}
```

//should store position in the innerHTML of an element called GeoElem

```
function Geo() { 

               var x = document.getElementById("GeoElem");

               function showPosition(position) {
                   x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + ";" + position.coords.longitude;
               }

               if (navigator.geolocation) {
                   x.innerHTML = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
               }
               else {
                   x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
               }
                //return x.innerHTML;

}
```

//this function should return pure text, stripped of html

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

===============
proof that my main function (Geo) works:....however, when you put everything together as in the example above it returns undefined instead of the coordinates, in the url.

this is a functional example that returns the coordinates on the screen in an html element, but I want them returned by a function as attempted above

```
<p id="idx"></p>
<script>
        var x = document.getElementById("idx");

               function showPosition(position) {
                   x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + ";" + position.coords.longitude;
               }

               if (navigator.geolocation) {
                   x.innerHTML = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
               }
               else {
                   x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
               }
</script>
```

Note. It would be nicer to have the coordinates returned by the function Geo directly, without storing them into the innerHTML of an element, but this didn't work:

```
function handle_geolocation_query() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var position = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };

                var lat = position.lat;
                var long = position.lng;
                return (lat + ';' + long);
            })
        }
```

Either one of the two methods will do. Either directly calculate it and return it from the function or through an html element grab it and pass it on like this `window.location.href = window.location.href + "/search/" + handle_geolocation_query();` in `myFunct3`

Comment: Could it be because your HTML syntax is incorrect? If you can provide a jsfiddle, that would be the best.

Comment: Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/zabeetles/8cv8mdma/ but it's best copied on local in an html, i think the fiddler is protected against showing location, which this example attempts to do (user receives a prompt to agree), this is owed to geolocation concept - a similar example here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation
The twist is i need the info in a function to concatenate it to the url.

Comment: `<p id="idx">` needs a closing tag `</p>`

Comment: thank you, i've fixed that in the original question. same issue though

Comment: @zabeetles Everything is working properly with slight modification to work on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8cv8mdma/1/ I don't know why yours didn't work

Comment: Daniel, do you also get on the screen something like: `28.4335;39.0510953 (your location)
file:///C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/file.html/search/undefined`
? This proves that the part where it calculates the innerhtml works, but the redirecting in the browser still doesn't work (it puts undefined after search). 
Wondering if this is to do with the clicking event...

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {

  var x = document.getElementById("id22");

  function showPosition(position) { //When the user allows Geolocation, you could get the position, otherwise you can't
    x.innerHTML = position  !== undefined ? position.coords.latitude + ";" + position.coords.longitude : "You don't have allow Geo";
  }

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);  //At this point, the Geolocation is ever undefined
    x.innerHTML = 'Please allow Geo!';
  }
  else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }

}
```

The function `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` doesn't return anything (see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) so per default it returns undefined.

Hopes it helps.

Comment: I have update your jsfiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/8cv8mdma/2](https://jsfiddle.net/8cv8mdma/2/) . The main problem is the undefined in the url. This is caused, because the url is build before the function returns the geolocation. Your code is working async, so you must build the url after the result is there.